# swift save multiple images from collection view to firebase storage and get downloadURL?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tOaj.png)Please help me I want to upload multiple image from my uicollectionview to firebase Storage and show downloadURL in Realtime database

i have try to search a lot but it no one work for me.

i can import the pictures from libray and make it show in myCollectionView but i don't know how to save it in to firebase.

```
Reports
     -(userID)
        -(reportID) - Using childByAutoId
            - where i want to save to image
```

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ProblemViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var reportID : String!
    var phonNumber : String!

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    @IBOutlet weak var problemButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var problemImage: UIImageView!

    var images = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.myCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.myCollectionView.dataSource = self

        retrieveUser()
        generateReportID()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .camera, target: self, action: #selector(importPicture))

    }

    @IBAction func sendProblemAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //TODO: Storage image and Send information to Firebase and save it in our database
        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = storage.reference().child("product_images/\(userID)/report/\(imageName).jpg")
        if let uploadImage = problemImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.15) {

            storageRef.putData(uploadImage, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }

                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString

                    let post = ["report_image_url": downloadURL!] as [String : Any]

                    self.registerUserIntoDatabase(userID: self.userID, values: post as [String : AnyObject])

                })
            }
        }
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }

    private func registerUserIntoDatabase(userID: String, values: [String:AnyObject]){
        //TODO: Send information to Firebase and save it in our database
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let usersRef = ref.child("Reports").child("\(userID)/\(reportID!)")
        usersRef.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
        })
    }

    func generateReportID () {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        guard let key = self.ref.child("Reports").child("\(userID)/\(String(describing: reportID))").childByAutoId().key else { return }
        reportID = key
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageView", for: indexPath)

        if let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as? UIImageView {
            imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]
        }
        return cell
    }

    @objc func importPicture() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "picture", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }

        dismiss(animated: true)

        images.insert(image, at: 0)
        myCollectionView.reloadData()
        print("key = \(image)")
    }
}
```

I want to upload multiple images that show in uicollectionview to my firebase storage and show downloadURL in realtime database.

like this

```
Reports
     -(userID)
        -(reportID) - Using childByAutoId
            - image1 : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
            - image2 : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
            - image3 : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
            - image4 : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
```

[My UICollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tOaj.png)
  When i press save it will error like this

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhX9r.png)

Comment: Tell us it's not working is not a lot to go on. What isn't working? Did you add a breakpoint to the code and step through it to see which line isn't working? Do that, update your question and we'll take a look.

Comment: It's will error when i press save button to save image in to Firebase

```
if let uploadImage = problemImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.15) {
```

Line above will error 

"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Right. So problemImage is nil. You should address that by ensuring it's populated before trying to use it.

Comment: do you have an example how to address it

Comment: "key = <UIImage: 0x600002680850> size {748, 494} orientation 0 scale 1.000000"
This is the value that i get when i print image after choose image

Comment: What I am saying is the problemImage is the problem and attempting to use it by force unwrapping it when it's nil will crash your app. Change `if let uploadImage = problemImage.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.15) {` to just `if let uploadImage = problemImage.image {` and then inside that closure work with the uploadImage as you know it's not nil.